# Celery Django Daemon Multiple Virtual Environment

Tags: django, celery, virtualenv, daemon, django-celery

My problem is the following:

I have a django app on which I can upload files. When a file is uploaded, a celery task is launched to process the file on a specific queue depending of its version like the following:

```
import my_library

@app.task()
def process_file(file):
    result = my_library.process(file)
    model = MyModel(result=result)
    model.save()
    return

def file_upload(request):
    file = request.FILE['file']
    version = parse_version(file)
    process_file.run_async(file, queue=version)
```

So I have a queue for each version of my library. My idea was to create multiple daemon, one for each queue/version of my library using virtual environments to use the correct version of my_library.

But I don't know how to correctly do that.

my_library with different versions cannot coexist because they contains Cython functions with dependency on a custom C library with the same version number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- create a separate virtualenv for each version of the library you need to run
- install the appropriate library inside each virtualenv
- install your code in the virtualenv
- use supervisord to run a separate celery worker for each version/virtualenv. Each worker listens to a different queue
- dipatch the task to the appropriate queue

`/etc/supervisor.d/celery.conf`

```
[program:celery-version-1]
command = /path/to_venv_version_1/bin/python manage.py celery worker -Q version-1 ....

[program:celery-version-2]
command = /path/to_venv_version_2/bin/python manage.py celery worker -Q version-2 ....

[program:celery-version-3]
command = /path/to_venv_version_3/bin/python manage.py celery worker -Q version-3 ....
```

then dispatch your tasks:

```
def file_upload(request):
    file = request.FILE['file']
    version = parse_version(file)
    process_file.run_async(file, queue=version)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. 
One more question, I was currently using launchd to run celery as a deamon. Do you know how I could do a similar thing with launchd?

Comment: I have no experience with launchd, sorry

Comment: Don't worry I'll try to implement your solution and accept with some modifications if needed. Thanks again.

Comment: Using Supervisor instead of launchd was a very nice advice in this case becaus it allows to manage versionning quite easily in a single  supervisor/celery.conf file which is great.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you - supervisor is a great piece of software which can make life easier in many cases. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing code versioning and business logic - that's not a good idea.

You are better off having one version of the code with a different function for each version of the file.

Comment: It's not a simple function. It's a Cython function with dependency on a custom C library with the same version number.

Comment: I'd suggest updating your answer with this information.